# Remove ImageView from Gridpane

Tags: java, user-interface, gridpane

I am programming a game in Java. It's kind of like a labyrinth. If a player clicks on a cell on a gridpane the player image moves there and I am struggling with removing the playerImage from the old position.

Here is how i am creating the imageViews:

```
private ImageView[][] initImages() {
    int colcount = gridPane.getColumnConstraints().size();
    int rowcount = gridPane.getRowConstraints().size();
    imageViews = new ImageView[colcount][rowcount];
    // bind each Imageview to a cell of the gridpane
    int cellWidth = (int) gridPane.getWidth() / colcount;
    int cellHeight = (int) gridPane.getHeight() / rowcount;
    for (int x = 0; x < colcount; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < rowcount; y++) {
            //creates an empty imageview
            imageViews[x][y] = new ImageView();
            //image has to fit a cell and mustn't preserve ratio
            imageViews[x][y].setFitWidth(cellWidth);
            imageViews[x][y].setFitHeight(cellHeight);
            imageViews[x][y].setPreserveRatio(false);
            imageViews[x][y].setSmooth(true);
            //add the imageview to the cell and
            //assign the correct indicees for this imageview, so you later can use GridPane.getColumnIndex(Node)
            gridPane.add(imageViews[x][y], x, y);
            //the image shall resize when the cell resizes
            imageViews[x][y].fitWidthProperty().bind(gridPane.widthProperty().divide(colcount));
            imageViews[x][y].fitHeightProperty().bind(gridPane.heightProperty().divide(rowcount));
        }
    }
```

and here is how i draw a Player on a OnClickEvent

```
public RealGUI drawPlayer(int playerNumber, CellCoordinates coords) {
    Image img = null;
    switch (playerNumber) {
        case 1:
            img = new Image("/gui/img/Bob_trans.png");
            break;
        case 2:
            // trans Bild Spieler 2
            img = new Image("/gui/img/Bob_trans.png");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("Problem mit Spielernummer");
    }

    ImageView newImgView = new ImageView();
    newImgView.fitHeightProperty().bind(this.gridPane.heightProperty()
            .divide(this.gridPane.getRowConstraints().size()));
    newImgView.setImage(img);
    this.gridPane.add(newImgView, coords.getX(), coords.getY());
    return this;
}
```

My basic question is: How to I remove the Player Imageview on the GridPane?

Thank you very much,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you can try. Whenever you move a player, *remove* the current image at the destination and add the player image to the destination. Also remove the player image from the previous location and add an *empty* image there. Here's the generic syntax:

```
gridPane.getChildren().remove(currImg); 
gridPane.add(newImg, 1,0);
```

Note that you need references to the images (players, empties) you are adding and removing.